# Saving jags.model in RData file

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

Is there any way to save a jags.model() object into a RData or txt file ?

To perform MCMC on a better computer, I have to save my model on one and using it in a new workspace. But I've some difficulty to use "save()" and "load()" function on R.
Thanks for your advices.

*Added:*

I tried:

> jags <- jags.model('regression.bug',
>                     data = my.data,
>                     n.chains = 4,
>                     n.adapt = 1000)

Then I would like save "jags"

> save( jags , file="jags.RData")

It's look like if it's saved. But, when I try:

> ld.jags <- load( "jags.RData" )
>
> ld.jags
>
> [1] "jags"

And I don't know How I could use "ld.jags" to perform my analysis.

Comment: You mention problems with `save` and `load` which are what I'd typically suggest using.  Can you add further detail to your question about what you've tried and the problems you encountered when doing so please?

Comment: `load` will restore a list object to the global environment with the name that it had when saved. `id.jags` is now a character value that has the same characters as the name of that object but it is not the R name. `names` are language objects.  If you type the uncommented characters `jags` at the command line you should see the results of `print(jags)`. You don't say what you mean by "perform your analysis"; `jags` is already the results of an earlier analysis.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using `coda` to perform some post-analysis such as `gelman.plot()`, or even a simple `plot()` which is very long to perform because of the uge number of params. I perform JAGS on a computer for 2-3hours and then I would like to save the result on a file for further analysis on another PC. So How can I do?

Comment: Do you just want to save the posterior samples for analysis with `coda`?  Or do you need to save the model object so that you can update the chains and draw more posterior samples?